# Assertion failure on UITableView when calling deleteRowsAtIndexPaths

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have two table views from which I can move data from table1 to table2 when pressing a button.

When the cell's are selected a checkmark appears and a the button is pressed the following things happen:

- remove object from array data source
- call `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`

My problem is that when the data is transfered to table2, the data still has the checkmark on table2 cell's. I want to reset it, but in every place I tried to iterate the objects array and set the checkmark to false, when `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` is called the following error occurs:

```
Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3491.2.5/UITableView.m:1717
```

Anyone knows why this is happening ?

Comment: How are you tracking the checkmarks?  Is there more to the assertion/exception message?

Comment: The cell are loaded with some objects that have a bool checked property which tell's you if the cell is checkmarked or not. And that is entire error which I see in Xcode.

Comment: Normally you will get a message that indicates that the number of rows in the tableview didn't match the starting number plus/minus the insertions/deletions

Comment: It's weird because I just change a property an the existing cells. Than I delete them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is critical that you update your data source before notifying the the view of any changes. The view methods assume that your data source contains the currently correct data. If it does not, the table view might receive the wrong set of items from your data source or ask for items that are not there and crash your app.

Try doing it in this order:

- copy the object at table A into a new item (with property unchecked)
- remove object from array data source of table A
- call deleteRowsAtIndexPaths for table A
- insert copied object at step 1 to the data source of table B
- reload table B

also providing the code where you insert the item to table B could be helpful.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to iterate the objects array and set the checkmark to false

That's not the way you do it.

In cellAtRowIndexPath you should have a condition to show or hide the check mark.

When you delete a cell, delete from the datasource as well and reload the tableView. Very important:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: I have that condition in cellAtRowIndexPath, but then when I press the button to transfer the items to the other table, where exactly should I change my checkmark ?

Comment: The information if a cell should be check mark or not should be provided from the datasource